# Migrate an Laravel app to a domain subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm gona to migrate a Laravel application from domain

[1] http://example.com

to

[2] https://example.com/app.

Currently on [1] Some clients do a request like 'GET /some'. After host the app on [2] the request is 'GET app/some'.

How do I smoothly make routes to answer as it has been called from [1] so I do not change every route adding the `app` prefix?

Right now I have to modify all routes (around 50) like this:

```
Route::get('app/some', function () {
});
```

I'm using Laravel 5.2 (yes, it is old).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `RouteServiceProvider` class, find the `boot` method, then add a prefix to your web routes.

**The original:**

```
 Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

**To:**

```
Route::prefix('app')
                ->middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

**In Laravel old versions:**

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'app','namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',],
```

Comment: My `RouteServiceProvider` is more like `$router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',], function ($router) {` ...

Comment: @Plinio.Santos I think you can add it like  $router->group(['prefix' => 'app','namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',], function ($router) {

Comment: Run 'php artisan route:clear' after changing the 'RouteServiceProvider'

Comment: Still getting a NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php: "GET /index.php" 404

Comment: Great news! I will change my answer to add the solution specific to Laravel 5.2.

Answer (score 2):

Try and use route prefix. Here is the code example from the Laravel official docs itself.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('users', function ()    {
        // Matches The "/admin/users" URL
    });
});
```

In your case replace 'admin ' with 'app'
Link to docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-prefixes

Comment: There isn't an easiest way like a middleware to rewrite 'app/some' to 'some'? I'd like to not change my routes since there are many clients relying on 'some' scheme...

Comment: You can follow the answer above as suggested by changing the route service provider. But that way all paths will ALWAYS have the app prefix and you will loose future flexibility. If you use my suggested method, you can have different paths with/without the prefix.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't have to separately add a group prefix for each route. Just put one around all the paths you need and it will work.

Comment: Exactly. My question is about do minimal changes to modify ALL routes to answer in a prefix. I'm sure your answer will also help many developers. Ty.